# How do I get the value of input fields and display it on the dialog box?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<dialog>

label id="show" label

label id="show1" label

</dialog>

var x = document.getElementById("name").value;
x = document.getElementById("show").innerHTML;

var y = document.getElementById("matrix").value;
y = document.getElementById("show1").innerHTML;
```

I used label form with only `id=""` and without `for=""` is it valid?

Also i'm trying to get the id(value) of the input and display it on the dialog box, is this the correct code to get it?

I used this code but failed to display the output on dialog box .. I'm still new in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Please make your question more clear.
Do you want to get text of label control?

If yes then you can use below jquery code :-

```
var x= $('#show').text();

var y= $('#show1').text();
```

**Edited**

Or if you want to show value of textbox into label of dialog than please try below code :-

```
var x= $("#textboxID").val()
```

And you can set this text to label:-

```
$("#LabelID").val(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit change in your code is needed,
problem in your code is you are not assigning your 'x' to any field

```
var x = document.getElementById("name").value;
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = x;
```

Here is a jsFiddle, check out here.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/subhajit06/6aL6muhL/)

Thanks